# Filter Rows based on multi level column

Tags: python, pandas, hierarchical-data

I'm trying to filter rows based on multi level column. I can't quite pinpoint if there is an error with my data

```
df[df[[('description','type')]].isin(["Filter1","Filter2"])]

>> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

If i try to convert to string i get the same error

```
df.loc[:,[('description','type')]] = df.loc[:,[('description','type')]].astype(str)

>> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

Data (first 5 rows with 2 columns included):

```
    description
    type        date
0   Filter 1    1 Mth-7/21
1   Filter 1    1 Yr-7/21
2   Filter 2    10 Yr-7/21
3   Filter 2    15 Yr-7/21
4   Filter 3    2 Yr-7/21
5   Filter 3    3 Mth-7/21
```

I'm not sure why it keeps throwing the first 2 errors when I think all my column values are all strings

Simple example that I have in mind that works:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({('description','type'):['a','b','c','d'],
                    ('description','value'):[1,2,3,4]})

df1[df1[('description','type')].isin(['a','b'])]
```

Comment: What is the output of `df.info()` and `df.columns`?

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 437 entries, 0 to 436
Columns: 755 entries, ('description', 'type') to ('description', 'type+date')
dtypes: float64(752), object(3)
memory usage: 2.5+ MB

Comment: MultiIndex([(               'description',                'type'),
            (               'description',                'date'),...  length=755)

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between your 2 filters:

```
df[df[[('description','type')]].isin(["Filter1","Filter2"])]
#    ^------------------------^--- HERE

df1[df1[('description','type')].isin(['a','b'])]
```

```
# First case: float appears
>>> df1[df1[[('description','type')]].isin(['a','b'])]
  description
         type value
0           a   NaN
1           b   NaN
2         NaN   NaN
3         NaN   NaN

# Second case
>>> df1[df1[('description','type')].isin(['a','b'])]

  description
         type value
0           a     1
1           b     2
```

Comment: if i take those extra brackets out i get: ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!

Comment: You need to update your post with a sample which raises the `TypeError`.

Comment: Is there a way to post the entire dataset?

Comment: `df.loc[:5, [('description','type'), ('description','value')]]`

Comment: ok i updated the post with my truncated dataframe. do you think error might be from the 'date' column not being in a standard datetime?

Comment: a crude work around: save df.to_excel('df.xlsx') then read back in df = pd.read_excel('df.xlsx',header=[0,1]) ... i'm guessing it has to do with the multi level columns ... i also did a transpose prior ... any input is helpful thanks!!